# Not able to reset background colour for ListView item

Tags: android, android-layout

In the custom Adaptor, I did the following in the ***getView*** method:

```
        if ( ual.getTransactionCategory() == TransactionCategory.WARNING ){
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(convertView.getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow_warning));
        }
        ...
        return convertView;
```

By setting the adaptor in the ListView, I sucessfully made the warning items displayed in a yellow background. Now, my problem is I want to set the background of the warning item to white as I click it. So in the ***onItemClick*** of the ListView, I did:

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        }
```

But it doesn't change the background.

Instead, if I don't set the background in the ***getView*** I can change the background to whatever I like in ***onItemClick***.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [state drawable resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). In this drawable you can define the color for different states. Then, when you are building the view, do this instead:

```
if ( ual.getTransactionCategory() == TransactionCategory.WARNING ){ 
    convertView. setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_state_drawable);
}
...
return convertView;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Actually I tried colour state list which should be similar to the state drawable resource but it doesn't do anything..

Answer (score 0):

You have make reference to your inner view from view. The below should work.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.menu_icon); //What ever your inline view is
        iv.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
}
```